# Android Webview not downloading PDF

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview

I can't get a PDF file to download in a webview in my app.

I have placed the webview in my android app and access the link to the PDF.  On iOS the same setup downloads the PDF, but in Android nothing happens.  I have tested the PDF link in the browser to ensure it's valid.  It also works in iOS.

In addition, the webview will display a webpage (like google) but will not download a PDF.  I've got a PDF reader installed on the device.

I have made sure that my manifest contains:  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

I've googled extensively and see that others have had this issue before but the solutions always seem overly complicated or intrusive (changing permissions in SELinx?).  This should be a common task with a straightforward answer, so I must be missing something obvious.

I'm stuck.  Any help appreciated.

Here is my webview code:

```
public class WebActivity extends MenuActivity {

public static final String TARGET_URL = "com.hawthornemackenzie.congressfoundationandroid.target_url";
private String mTargetURLString;
public WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
    mTargetURLString = getIntent().getStringExtra(TARGET_URL);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    // confirm the proper url is being pulled out of the intent...
    // An example url is: http://www.voorjaarsdagen.eu/media/com_vjd/vjd_abstracts/2017/A17206.pdf
    // Uncomment to test it directly:  mTargetURLString = "http://www.voorjaarsdagen.eu/media/com_vjd/vjd_abstracts/2017/A17206.pdf" <-- doesn't work, but URL in browser works
    // Uncomment to test it with google mTargetURLString = "http://www.google.com";   <-- works

    Log.d("\n\n\n LOG target url:", mTargetURLString);
    Toast.makeText(this, mTargetURLString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mWebView.loadUrl(mTargetURLString);

}
```

}

And here is the logcat output directly after this call:

```
    04-14 14:00:34.639 1259-1259/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for service=batteryproperties scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:healthd_service:s0 tclass=service_manager
04-14 14:00:34.771 30309-30434/com.hawthornemackenzie.congressfoundationandroid W/chromium: [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(423)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
04-14 14:00:34.779 30309-30325/com.hawthornemackenzie.congressfoundationandroid D/FA: Connected to remote service
04-14 14:00:34.812 1260-2994/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 2 and usage 0x933 imply creation of host color buffer
04-14 14:00:34.926 1929-2055/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.hawthornemackenzie.congressfoundationandroid/.WebActivity: +541ms

[ 04-14 14:00:34.937 30309:30454 D/         ]
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa13a5d80, tid 30454
04-14 14:00:34.942 1260-1293/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 2 and usage 0x933 imply creation of host color buffer
04-14 14:00:35.079 1260-1293/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x933 imply creation of host color buffer
04-14 14:00:35.183 1260-1260/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
04-14 14:00:35.560 30309-30309/com.hawthornemackenzie.congressfoundationandroid W/BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 30309
04-14 14:01:00.129 1260-1327/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 210 syncs in 60s
04-14 14:02:00.062 1260-1327/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 2 syncs in 60s
```

Comment: `WebView` cannot display PDFs on its own. If your goal is to simply download a PDF, use an HTTP client API, like `HttpURLConnection`, then hand it over to a PDF viewer via an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`. Or, consider `DownloadManager`.

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare!  That got me started in the right direction.  I had tunnel vision that it was going to be WebView.  The answer, with your help, was trivial:                Uri uri = Uri.parse(ApplicationSettings.terms_url);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent); -- that was all the code needed to start the browser and load the pdf.  Thanks again.

Comment: Note that your solution will be limited to PDF viewers that handle `http` or `https` schemes. Some PDF viewers will assume that other apps (e.g., a browser) handle that and only support `file` and `content` themselves. If these are just terms of service or something else simple, you will have better compatibility just converting those into HTML and using `WebView` or a Web browser. In particular, packaging the terms as assets and showing them with `WebView` prevents any problems due to lack of connectivity.

Comment: Awesome thanks.  In this case, I know the content providers will be only using http/s so we are good to go.  But thanks for the heads up as I'm sure I'll be doing more of this type of thing in the next app.